# I'm trying to figure out how to insert parentheses and a dash to a phone number that is the output. I'm using python 3.5

Tags: python

the first part works fine but the second part after else doesn't. I can't get it to work so that the output phoneNumber from above formats into (XXX)XXX-XXXX) for example if I enter 9999999999 above I want the below to add the parentheses and and the dash.

```
def main():
phoneNumber=int(input("Enter a 10 digit unformatted telephone number in the format ##########: "))
length = len("phoneNumber")
index=0


if (length ==10):
    phoneNumber=True
if phoneNumber:
    print("The unformatted number is: ",phoneNumber)

else:
    print("The telephone number was NOT entered in unformatted format ##########.")


phoneNumber= phoneNumber.insert(0,"(")
phoneNumber= phoneNumber.insert(4,")")
phoneNumber= phoneNumber.insert(8,"-")
print("The formatted number is: ",phoneNumber)


main()
```

Comment: I think you've already got it.  Just remove the conversion to int on the input line.

Comment: I tried it and it's still not working

Answer (score 0):

The insert function is not allowed for strings and ints. You can use this modified function directly.:

```
def main():
    phoneNumber=int(input("Enter a 10 digit unformatted telephone number in the format ##########: "))
    tempNumber = []
    phoneNumber = str(phoneNumber)
    length = len(phoneNumber)
    index=0
    print(length)


    if (length ==10):
        print("The unformatted number is: ",phoneNumber)
    else:
        print("The telephone number was NOT entered in unformatted format ##########.")

    for num in phoneNumber:     # string to list conversion by iteration
        tempNumber.append(num)

    tempNumber.insert(0,"(")
    tempNumber.insert(4,")")
    tempNumber.insert(8,"-")
    phoneNumber = ''.join(tempNumber)
    print(phoneNumber)

main()
```